# Floating my drop down navigation bar

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am having some problem getting my navigation bar to work. Here is the desired output for my navigation bar: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/EEfPH/).

I am trying to make it so that when the user hovers the top level of the navigation bar, a drop down list is shown.

However, the second level of my navigation bar is just floating around. How can I style it?

This is my HTML:

```
  <div id="menubar">
    <ul id="menu">
      <li class="selected"><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Volunteers</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="">Add</a></li>
      <li><a href="">View</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Update</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Packaging Session</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="">Add</a></li>
      <li><a href="">View</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Update</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#menubar
{ width: 900px;
  height: 72px;
  padding: 0;
  background: #1293EE;} 

ul#menu, ul#menu li
{ float: left;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;}

ul#menu li
{ list-style: none;}

ul#menu li a
{ letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  font: normal 100% arial, sans-serif;
  display: block; 
  float: left; 
  height: 37px;
  padding: 29px 26px 6px 26px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: transparent;} 

ul#menu li a:hover, ul#menu li.selected a, ul#menu li.selected a:hover
{ color: #FFF;
  background: #0D66A5;}

ul#menu li ul li a
{
display: none;
height: auto;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
position:absolute;
}
```

In google chrome:

[image]

In Internet Explorer:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I can see the connection to C#. Can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry, I added the wrong tag. It supposed to be html

Comment: You should put a jsfiddle up, with your latest version of the code showing the problem. I don't get the behaviour in your pictures, in IE, using the HTML/CSS you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of hiding every `a` tag in the dropdown, rather hide the entire `ul`, and use that as the position element, and style the `li`'s and `a`'s as any other element.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gd2SX/

Look for the area, that says "Added styles".

Comment: But how come when I browse using google chrome, the navigation bar is messed up. And when I browse with firefox, the drop down does not shows at all. And in IE, the drop down float up?

Comment: It looks the same in my IE and Chrome. I'd say you should probably start over, using the technique I used in my fiddle though.

Answer (score 0):

HTMLDog made a very interesting and comprehensive article about floating menus: [Sons of Suckerfish](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/).

You will be particularly interested in [the part about dropdowns](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/), and particularly **[the sample they provide](http://www.htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/example/)**.

It will help you correct much more than just your floating problem.

---

For your particular problem, I suggest that you disable the hiding of the menus, style everything to look perfect as if all the submenus were open, and then re-activate the hiding of submenus:

```
/* Lists directly inside list-items. */
li>ul {
  display: none;
}
/* Lists directly inside hovered list-items. */
li:hover>ul,
li.selected>ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Then you will find it much easier to fix.